# create new movieclip from class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to Flash AS3.I am trying to create a movie clip> I have created basic code but i need to convert it t package so i can create XX number of clips from it.

Can you help in making this simple package so I can use it like var btn:Button = new Button("title");

```
// mc_main
var mc_main:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
//mc.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x0000CC);  
mc_main.graphics.beginFill(0x0000CC);
mc_main.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 40);
mc_main.graphics.endFill();
mc_main.x = 80;
mc_main.y = 60;
addChild(mc_main);

//mc_txt
var mc_txt:TextField = new TextField();
mc_main.addChild(mc_txt);
mc_txt.text = 'Hello!';
mc_txt.x = 50;
mc_txt.y = 8;
//mc_txt Color
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.size = 18;
tf.bold = true;
tf.font = "Arial"
tf.color = 0xFFFFFF;
mc_txt.setTextFormat(tf);
```

**I came up with code this but doesnt work**

```
package com.fladev.button
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class Button extends MovieClip   
    {
        private var Title:String;
        private var Image:String;
        public static var mc_main:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

        public function Button(Title:String, Image:String) {
            this.Title = Title;
            this.Image = Image;
            Draw_main();
        }
        private function Draw_main()
        {        
            mc_main.graphics.beginFill(0x0000CC);
            mc_main.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 40);
            mc_main.graphics.endFill();
            mc_main.x = 80;
            mc_main.y = 60;
            this.stage.addChild(mc_main);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @putvande:Can you provide solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mc_main variable has no reason to be static.

Also, don't add it to the stage; add it to the instance of Button.

Comment: Can you explain what u mean by "add it to the instance of Button." ?

Comment: To simply do `addChild(mc_main)` or `this.addChild(mc_main)` (both are the same) instead of `this.stage.addChild(mc_main);`